# Show groups with 0 group_by dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe eg.

```
a<-data.frame(
   year=c(2001,2001,2002,2004,2001,2002,2004),
   binary=c(1,0,1,0,1,0,0))
```

I try for example:

```
a %>% group_by(year) %>% count()
```

I would like the output:

```
year    binary   n
2001    0        1
2001    1        1
2002    1        1
2002    0        1
2004    0        1
2004    1        0
```

I want to plot how many samples have the 1 phenotype but group_by deos not show a 1 group for 2004 because it has count 0.  How can I make it do so?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to count, and what do you mean by "does not show a 1 group for 2004"? Also, why does your desired output only show one 2004 line?

Comment: ? it doesn't it shows two.  Essentially I have a binary phenotype for thousands of samples which I would like to group by year and summarise the number of 1s and 0s but show both groups even when the count is 0.

Comment: Oh, sorry, don't know how I missed it. I'm still not sure why one has n=1 and one has n=0...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for `tidyr::complete()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

a<-data.frame(
  year=c(2001,2001,2002,2004,2001,2002,2004),
  binary=c(1,0,1,0,1,0,0))

a %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  count(binary) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  complete(year, binary, fill = list(n = 0))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>    year binary     n
#>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2001      0     1
#> 2  2001      1     2
#> 3  2002      0     1
#> 4  2002      1     1
#> 5  2004      0     2
#> 6  2004      1     0
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Great job translating this question